# Create own (custom) modifier in MaxScript

Tags: maxscript

I want to create my own modifier for the object.
So when I select the object, go to `Modify Panel` and expand the list of modifiers, `myModifier` will shows up.

What would be the simples way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to derive a new maxscript class from either Modifier, SimpleMod, or one of the existing modifiers (depending on your needs).

A simple modifier that just moves vertices around is best done from SimpleMod.  Here is the sample from the docs.  There are more examples in the documentation http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/14/ENU/MAXScript%20Help%202012/files/GUID-E91909AD-28D5-4AEF-8C6C-2EF2AC0C78A-1841.htm

```
plugin simpleMod saddle
name:"SaddleDeform"
classID:#(685325,452281)
version:1
(
  parameters main rollout:params
  (
    amount type:#integer ui:amtSpin default:20
  )
  rollout params "Saddle Parameters"
  (
    spinner amtSpin "Amount: " type:#integer range:[0,1000,20]
  )
  on map i p do
  (
    p.z += amount * sin((p.x * 22.5/extent.x) * (p.y * 22.5/extent.y))
    p
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I noticed you answered both my MaxScript questions :)

Comment: NP :).  I get a tonne of help from the community, so I give back where I can!